# What does the 3rd edition of Fact, Fiction, and Forecast say about grue?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language, induction

On my [website](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/grue.html), I have reproduced the passages from Nelson Goodman's book *Fact, Fiction, and Forecast* that define his famous predicate *grue* (and related predicates such as *emeruby*). In fact, I have scrupulously noted minor differences in different editions of the book.  However, so far, I have not been able to obtain a copy of the 3rd edition.

Could someone who has access to the 3rd edition please tell me what textual differences, if any, exist in the 3rd edition (in the aforementioned passages about *grue*, that is)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the third edition. I have the fourth edition, which has been around since 1983. Looking at your web page, I think you are right to interpret Goodman as saying that a species of object is grue if future observations of specimens of that species are blue after a certain time, rather than as saying that being grue means that previously observed specimens change colour.

As a slight aside, emeralds are always green. 'Emerald' is the name given to green beryl. Blue beryl is called aquamarine. So, 'emerald' is itself a colour term, which complicates the example. I suspect that Goodman didn't know this, and if he had, he would have chosen a different example. Since lots of things can actually change colour, he might have been better served choosing a chemical element or compound as an example.

For myself, I don't think his choice of example is a good one. You say he would want a "maximally perverse example" to illustrate his point, but I think an example involving things being different colours at different times is too stretched to make a good example, and it has led many people to misunderstand his point. Some have dismissed his example as absurd, or have thought that there is a simple way to exclude such examples by distinguishing 'bent predicates' from others. But his fundamental argument is quite sound. For any given finite series of observations, there will always be any number of distinctly different predicates that are compatible with those observations, but which will make contrary predictions if projected. So we cannot construe inductive inference simply along the lines of the more observations we make of some predicate, the more likely future observations will conform to it. There is no simple syntactic or semantic way to identify which predicates are projectible and which are not. Doing that requires the hard labour of scientific research.

Comment: Good point about the definition of an emerald! But other than that, I don't see why his choice of example is not good. There are no things that are "different colors at different times" in his example. It's just that (in conventional language) all the green emeralds are discovered first and the blue emeralds are discovered afterwards.

Comment: True, but the timing of the change seems arbitrary, and the reason for the change is unexplained.